# Please check my code. won't return a right value

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f_totprice(int,int,int,int);

int main()

{
    int menu_1;
    int menu_2;
    int menu_3;
    int menu_4;
    int totprice;
    int received_money;

    while (1){
        printf("what do you want to order?\n");
        printf("pizza: ");
        scanf("%d",&menu_1);
        printf("cheese: ");
        scanf("%d",&menu_2);
        printf("curry: ");
        scanf("%d",&menu_3);
        printf("soup: ");
        scanf("%d",&menu_4);


        printf("======================================\n");

        totprice=f_totprice(menu_1,menu_2,menu_3,menu_4);
        printf("total price is %d\n",totprice); /* this part returns a wrong value */
        printf("received ");
        scanf("%d",&received_money);
        printf("Your change is %d",received_money-totprice);

    }

}

int f_totprice (int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int total;

    char price[]={500,1000,1500,2000};

    total=a*price[0]+b*price[1]+c*price[2]+d*price[3];

    return total;
}
```

so, i just wrote a code to make a simple menu and the price part doesn't return the total value of my function below.. it keeps saying "the total value is -600,-300,-190" etc instead of integers.  in my eyes there is nothing wrong with it. please help? :(

Comment: I bet that it doesn't say what you claim it says.

Comment: It worked after changing to int and it says -600,-588 etc. I have no idea why.

Comment: @user253719: give us your inputs and your output!! we are not fortune-tellers !

Answer (score 3):

```
    char price[]={500,1000,1500,2000};
```

Can you figure out why this cannot work?
You should find out how to turn on warnings on your compiler.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lies here

```
int f_totprice (int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int total;

    char price[]={500,1000,1500,2000};

    total=a*price[0]+b*price[1]+c*price[2]+d*price[3];

    return total;
}
```

Why are you using a `char` array,

Use `int` array

Answer (score -1):

You are using char array instead of interger array, and printing the output in integer type (%d), Hence it is printing the ASCII equivalent of the sum , Please change character array to integer array.

int price[]={500,1000,1500,2000};

Comment: according to your answer, this may be solved either by changing `price` array to int type or use `%c` in printf ?

Comment: Nothing in the question says ASCII. ASCII is a niche and archaic character set. When dealing with text data, it is essential that you know which character set and encoding are being used-it's probably not ASCII! (Linux: run `locale`; Windows: run `chcp`).

Comment: I am sorry If I wasn't clear, I didn't mean it can be fixed by making %c in printf, it has to be %d for printing and data type integer while assigning.